# AudioQueue's Peak Power Progression is too Gradual

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, audioqueue

I'm using the standard Apple [AudioQueue Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) from the AudioToolBox library to use my device's microphone. I am keeping track of the peak audio level in real time, and this is working well except it does not respond as expected to *uneven* changes in volume. The mPeakPower jumps appropriately high for sudden increases in volume (no problem there), but it decreases only gradually: if I feed my device a loud clap followed by silence it jumps up high, then immediately starts to *steadily* decrease until it reaches the actual current volume (this decrease can take up to 2 seconds). Ideally, a loud sound followed by silence should cause a spike which would immediately fall back to the ambient volume. I need to quickly respond to both increases and decreases in volume. Any insights? I assume this is happening because of a smoothing algorithm, but how can I get around it? Should I be using a different library?

Here's a snippet of my code in the AudioQueueInputCallback method.

```
AudioQueueLevelMeterState meters[2];
UInt32 dlen = sizeof(meters);
AudioQueueGetProperty(myQueue,kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentLevelMeterDB,meters,&dlen);
NSNumber *ambientVolume = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:meters[0].mPeakPower];
```

Thanks!